# Summing over Subsets of $\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... n \}$

Tags: summation, prime-numbers

I came across the function which counts distinct prime factors of a number. I then generalized the function $w$ to take as argument a set instead of a number and return the number of prime factors that are shared between them.

If $\underline{n} = \{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... n \}$, then $w(\; \underline{6}\; ) = 0.$ Some other examples: $w(\{2, 4, 6, 8 \}) = 1, w(\{15, 30, 45, 60 \}) = 2$.

Now, I'd like to sum all subsets of $\underline{n}$ by applying the function $w(J)$ to each subset $J$ of $\underline{n}$, where $|J|>1$. To put this into math form, let $\mathcal{P}(\underline{n})$ be the power set of $\underline{n}$. Then the set of sets $D(\underline{n}) = \mathcal{P}(\underline{n}) \backslash \{J; J \subseteq \underline{n}, |J| \le 1 \}$.

The quantity I would like to find is:
$$\sum_{J \in D(\underline{n})} w(J)$$

in terms of $w$. $J$ ranges across the sets in $D(A)$. I have tried using the binomial coefficient to get all possible subsets of one specific type of set, for instance those sets sharing one factor, two factors, etc., but I think I'm missing a basic trick for finding the relevant sets of $D(A)$ because there is always some subsets I've missed.

What is the best way to calculate the above sum in terms of $w$? I do not want to evaluate $w$ since I'd like to be able to apply the strategy you use in your answer to a variety of functions that take as argument a set and return an integer based on the factors of the elements in the set. I want to know how to break up $D(n)$ into *all* the relevant subsets to count them.

Comment: This seems difficult. One approach that may work is to break the function $w$ into $w_2 + w_3 + w_5 + w_7 + \cdots$, where $w_p(J)$ equals $1$ if every element in $J$ is divisible by $p$ and $0$ otherwise. Then the sums $\sum_{J \in D(\underline{n})} w_p(J)$ seem like they could be computed by induction on $n$.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: you want to know a good way to enumerate the sets in $D(\underline n)$? Why the long explanation of $w$ if you do not want to evaoluate it? This confuses me.

Comment: @M.Winter Yes, you are correct. I'm not sure how I could edit the question to say "enumerate the sets $D(n)$" without losing the context.

Comment: @LinusRastegar Are you doing this with some math software? E.g. Mathematica. Or by hand? And do you know how to enumerate all subsets of a set? E.g. Mathematica code looks like this `DD[n_] := Subsets[Range[2, n], {2, n - 1}]`.

Comment: @M.Winter I'm not using Mathematica, hoping to do it by hand. I don't know an efficient way to enumerate all the subsets.

Comment: @LinusRastegar This seems to be the real problem. I guess you can find a lot of posts on Math.SE explaining how to enumerate subsets, one of my own is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2305385/415941) (it explains this in the context of programming). But *efficient* is not so easy because there are already $2^{n-1}$ subsets of $\underline n$ and only $n+{n-1\choose 2}=\mathcal O(n^2)$ will be excluded by your restrictions.

Comment: @M.Winter Thanks for the reference. What are your thoughts on the current answer to the question?

Comment: @LinusRastegar It gives a nice answer to the question how to compute this specific sum over $w(J)$ in your question. If this is really helpful for you, then you should accept, but if it is as you said and this was only an example without any value in itself, i.e. $w$ will be replaced by many other functions and you are actually interested in how to enumerate $D(\underline n)$, then this answer misses the point. This however should tell you that there can and should be something done in order to clarify the intention of your post (do you know what you want to know?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculating your desired sum is easier if you "partition" the sets in $D(
\underline{n})$ not into those with zero, one, two, etc. prime factors but into those divisible by $2$, $3$, $5$, $7$, and so forth. ("Partition" is quoted here because obviously this isn't a true partition; some sets will reoccur.) Let $w_p(J)$ be $1$ if every element in $J$ is divisible by $p$, and $0$ otherwise. Let $S_p(n) = \sum_{J \in D(\underline{n})} w_p(J)$. The number of subsets of $\{1, \ldots, n\}$ (starting from $2$ instead of $1$ makes no difference) in which every element is divisible by $p$ is the same as the number of nonempty subsets of $\{1, \ldots, \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor\}$, namely $2^{\lfloor n/p \rfloor}$. Elimintating the zero- and one-element sets gives $$S_p(n) = 2^{\lfloor n/p \rfloor} - \left\lfloor \frac{n}{p} \right\rfloor- 1$$ and of course $$S(n) = \sum_{\substack{2 \leq p \leq n/2 \\ p\, \text{prime}}} S_p(n)$$ which is a sum for which I wouldn't expect a convenient closed form to exist.

Comment: This is pretty clever: even if $w(J) > 1$, it will be counted the correct number of times due to the overlap! Very cool. I'm assuming the $2^{\lfloor n/p \rfloor}$ was produced by summing over the binomial coefficient and then simplifying. Is this correct? Thanks for the concise answer, I'll see if I kind find any problems or suggestions.

Comment: The $2^{\lfloor n/p\rfloor}$ is because every set $\{k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_m\}$ of positive integers all at most $n$ and all divisible by $p$ corresponds uniquely to a set $\{k_1/p, k_2/p, \ldots, k_m/p\}$ of positive integers all at most $n/p$ - in fact, all at most $\lfloor n/p \rfloor$, as there can be no integers between $\lfloor n/p\rfloor$ and $n/p$. There are $2^{\lfloor n/p \rfloor}$ such sets, including the zero- and one-element sets.